# Finding the index of an NA value in a vector

Tags: r, vector, na

I have the following vector:

```
x <- c(3, 7, NA, 4, 8)
```

And I just want to know the index of the `NA` in the vector. If, for instance, I wanted to know the index of `7`, the following code would work:

```
> which(x == 7)
[1] 2
```

I find it odd that running the same code when trying to find the index of the `NA` does not give me the desired result.

```
> which(x == NA)
integer(0)
```

I also tried the following but it does not work:

```
>  which(x == "NA")
integer(0)
```

Your help will be much appreciated.

Edit

The question has been answered below by @ccapizzano, but can anyone explain why the codes above do not work?

Comment: @Ben, nice use of the gold badge superpowers.

Comment: @SavedByJESUS `"NA"` is character and `NA` is special type of variable. It is not possible to compare `NA`  using `==`. For this purpose you have `is.na` function. Anything compared to `NA` using `==` will result to `NA` (you want index not `NA`). Try following: `NA == "NA"` AND `NA == NA`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You may want to try using the `which` and `is.na` functions in the the following manner:

```
which(is.na(x))
[1] 3
```

Comment: It seems not to work when used with pipe `%>% which(is.na(.))`

Comment: @AlvaroMorales It actually works if you use the pipe all the way. For example: `x %>% is.na() %>% which()`